# MSMQ Version Details Using Windows Command

Tags: msmq

Is there any command which helps in getting the Version Of MSMQ software installed on Windows server 2008?

In my scenario MSMQ registry path is HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\ .

I Tried the below command but it gave the sub values too

REG QUERY HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ /s

Comment: The version of MSMQ is linked to the operating system. It isn't a separate product so if you know the OS version then you know the MSMQ major version. What are you planning to do with the information?

Answer (score 1):

The full version of Windows (MSMQ) can be checked here with msinfo32 and winver or with registry here:

```
reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v BuildLabEx

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ProductName

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v CurrentBuildNumber

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v ReleaseId

reg query "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion" /v UBR
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know MSMQ but if the version value is located into `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters\` you should be able to use the PowerShell Property : `Get-ItemPropertyValue`.

For example :

> Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion' 'ProgramFilesDir'

Will return the value : **C:\Program Files**

Hope it can help!

Comment: Get-ItemPropertyValue : The term 'Get-ItemPropertyValue' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of 
the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:2 char:1
+ Get-ItemPropertyValue 'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion' 'Program ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (Get-ItemPropertyValue:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

Comment: Thank you for the response I tried the command you gave it gave me an error I think am suppose to install the module and have to try this command .

Comment: Thanks all am able to pull the version details with the below command

Comment: get-itemproperty -path Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSMQ\Parameters | format-table

Comment: Get-ItemPropertyValue may not work in older versions of PowerShell.

Answer (score 0):

The MSMQ version is linked to the operating system: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Message_Queuing.

That would be 4.0 for Windows Server 2008 and 5.0 for Windows Server 2008 R2.